# Lollipop Google Agenda Colorpicker custom or...?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, color-picker

I was wondering if anyone knows if this colorpicker is custom or in Lollipop library?
This is how it looks on my LG G3 Android Lollipop - In the basic calendar app.
On my friends phone tough, it does not look like this.

I like this colorpicker to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3/src/com/android/calendar) is the source code for the Calendar app in Android 5.1 revision 3. Check out the CalendarColorPickerDialog.java.

That class extends from another class called ColorPickerDialog.java. You will find the ColorPicker project [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker/+/android-5.1.0_r3/src/com/android/colorpicker).

Pretty interesting thing you pointed out. I am also thinking of using them!  :D

Comment: If this is the answer you have been looking for, then please mark it as correct.   :)